# Console Application to Winform Application in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have tried this console app and it is a working but when i tried to apply the same codes to create a winform app there is no error but there is no output either.

here is the code:

**Console**

```
Imports MT4API
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Try
        Dim symbol As String = "EURUSD"
        Dim dde As New MT4DDE("fxpro")
        AddHandler dde.OnQuote, AddressOf MT_OnQuote
        dde.Connect()
        dde.Subscribe(symbol)
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key...")
        Console.ReadKey()
        dde.Unubscribe(symbol)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Public Sub MT_OnQuote(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As QuoteEventArgs)
    Console.WriteLine(args.Symbol & " " & args.Bid & " " & args.Ask)
End Sub
End Module
```

**WinForm**

```
Imports MT4API

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        Dim symbol As String = "EURUSD"
        Dim dde As New MT4DDE("cms")
        AddHandler dde.OnQuote, AddressOf Me.MT_OnQuote
        dde.Connect()
        dde.Subscribe(symbol)
        TextBox1.AppendText("Press any key...")
        dde.Unubscribe(symbol)
    Catch ex As Exception
        TextBox1.AppendText(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Public Sub MT_OnQuote(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As QuoteEventArgs)
    Try
        'TextBox1.AppendText(args.Symbol)
        TextBox1.Text += args.Symbol & vbCrLf
    Catch ex As Exception
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + ex.Message + vbCrLf
    End Try

End Sub


End Class
```

What seems to be the problem? Why the output on the console is not showing in the textbox on the winform.

Thank you very much.

Comment: WHy in console you have mentioned Fxpro where as in winform cms ?

Comment: What output do you get in the TextBox?

Comment: its is just for testing for "cms" and "fxpro".